# How to fix a System.FormatException when dropdownlist is set to default?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

I am having "An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code." Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format. I have a dropdown list, #Carriers, when user selects an item no errors occur, however, when user selects the dropdownlist back to default it show this error. I need a way to write an if statement to check for null values.

```
 [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public JsonResult LoadAccsByCarrierId(string carrierid)
    {

            var accsList = this.GetAccs(Convert.ToInt32(carrierid));
            var accsData = accsList.Select(m => new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text = m.AccessoryName,
                Value = m.AccessoryID.ToString(),
            });
            return Json(accsData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

     [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public JsonResult LoadPhonesByCarrierId(string carrierid, string emailaddress)
    {
        int id;
        var phonesData = new List<SelectListItem>();
        if (Int32.TryParse(carrierid, out id))
        {
            var phonesList = this.GetPhones(id, emailaddress);
            phonesData = phonesList.Select(m => new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text = m.Name,
                Value = m.PhoneID.ToString(),
            }).ToList();
            return Json(phonesData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else
            return null; 
    }
```

Comment: What's the content of carrierid? (Use a breakpoint too see it). https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k80ex6de(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: _I need a way to write an if statement to check for null values_ you mean like `if (value == null)`?

Comment: Carrier ID is "" when dropdown box is set to default. When a Carrier is selected it shows a value such as 1, 2, etc and no errors occur. It only occurs when nothing is selected from dropdown list.

Comment: I'm just guessing that's a way to fix the issue since it's not currently check for null values.

Comment: When I try to do if(carrierid != null) I get an error. "HomeController.LoadPhonesBycarrierId(string, string)': not all code paths return a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before calling the `Convert.ToInt32` method, you need to check the value of the string parameter and make sure it is some value which can be safely converted to an int value.

`Int32.TryParse` method will he handy

```
public JsonResult LoadAccsByCarrierId(string carrierid)
{
     int id;
     var accsData =new List<SelectListItem>();
     if (Int32.TryParse(carrierid, out id))
     {
        var accsList = this.GetAccs(id);
        accsData = accsList.Select(m => new SelectListItem()
        {
            Text = m.AccessoryName,
            Value = m.AccessoryID.ToString(),
        }).ToList();
     }
     return Json(accsData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

The above code currently returns an empty list of SelectListItem when the `carrierId` parameter value is not a valid numerical string value. Update the code to return everything (no filtering) as needed.

I also suggest to **use the appropriate types**. If carrierId is going to be always an int value or no value, you might consider using a nullable int and avoid the TryParse method call on string.

```
public ActionResult LoadAccByCarrierId(int? carrierId)
{
  if(carrierId!=null)
  {
       // to do : use carriedId.Value to do the Filtering
  }
  else
  {
    return something else 
  }
  // to do  : Return something
}
```

Comment: I get an error in the accsData. A  local or parameter bamed 'accsData' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter.

Comment: Sorry ! See the updated answer (removed the re-declaration of variable )

Comment: I updated my code when the error occurs. Both pop up with the same issues. Remove int id?

Comment: Did you try the solution i posted ?

Comment: I tried exactly what you posted but an error displays. accsData cnnot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter.

Comment: Did you try the fix i posted to the answer ? (removing var in front of accsData inside the if). See the updated answer.

Comment: Yea, I get a "cannot implicityly convert type 'System.Collections.eneric.IEnumerable.....are you missing a cast?

Comment: Add a `.ToList();` call to the end of `Select` method call. (Answer updated)

Comment: That helped. It doesn't display the error for public JsonResult LoadAccsByCarrierId(string carrierid). So, if I do the same thing for  public JsonResult LoadPhonesByCarrierId(string carrierid, string emailaddress) it should work. I will try to do it. If not, I will have to get back with you. Thank you!

Comment: I'm having issues with the string and int in the LoadPhonesByCarrierId.