# How to fix System.FormatException when dropdownlist is set to default?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

I have a drop down box that when an item is selected it has no errors, however, if user sets the drop down list to default it throws an error. The code that is not comment out is throwing an exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code. Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format. When I try to write the code that is comment out it gives me two errors. Not all code paths return a value and no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'emailaddress...(int, string)

```
      [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public JsonResult LoadPhonesByCarrierId(string carrierid, string emailaddress)
    {
        //int id;
        //var phonesData = new List<SelectListItem>();
        //if (Int32.TryParse(carrierid, out id))
        //{
        //    var phonesList = this.GetPhones(id);
        //    phonesData = phonesList.Select(m => new SelectListItem()
        //    {
        //        Text = m.Name,
        //        Value = m.PhoneID.ToString(),
        //    }).ToList();
        //    return Json(phonesData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        //}
        //}
        var phonesList = this.GetPhones(Convert.ToInt32(carrierid), emailaddress);
        var phonesData = phonesList.Select(m => new SelectListItem()
        {
            Text = m.Name,
            Value = m.PhoneID.ToString(),
        });
        return Json(phonesData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: Well yes - if `int.TryParse` returns false, what do you want to return?

Comment: carrerid doesn't seem to contain a value that can be converted to an integer.

Comment: This method is not very different than the other on you posted on [prev question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42836896/an-exception-occurs-when-dropdownlist-is-set-to-default/42837187#42837187). What is not working here ?

Comment: What is the value of carrierid when you get the exception?

Comment: The logic of what to return if carrier id is not a valid numeric value (so it cannot be converted to int) is totally up to you. The current code returns an empty list. you can return the full list without any filter. But it is up to you! We don't know your requirements.

Comment: Use the out commented code, it uses `int.TryParse` which is better than `Convert.ToInt32` because it handles invalid input without exception.

Comment: If you aren't getting the type of variable back that can be cast into an integer, you might need more stringent validation on the data being passed into this (in this case the carrierid).

Comment: I have a dropdownbox that has items. It returns 1, 2, 3, etc. An email is also entered in a textbox and that is what is return. However, when user selects the default on the dropdownbox it throws an error because it's a null value and it has an email address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the out commented code, it uses `int.TryParse` which is better than `Convert.ToInt32` because it handles invalid input without exception.

But you need to pass the email-adress to `GetPhones` and return  something(or throw an exception) if the `carrierid` was not a valid integer:

```
int id;
var phonesData = new List<SelectListItem>();
if (Int32.TryParse(carrierid, out id))
{
    var phonesList = this.GetPhones(id, emailaddress); // here
    phonesData = phonesList.Select(m => new SelectListItem()
    {
        Text = m.Name,
        Value = m.PhoneID.ToString(),
    }).ToList();
    return Json(phonesData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
else
   return null; // or throw an exception
```

Comment: What's the point in avoiding throwing an exception only to throw an exception? If throwing an exception is the desired behavior then just call the method throws an exception.

Comment: @Servy: i really must explain you what's the point in having meaningful exceptions? Maybe additional logging before the (meaningful) exception is thrown is also useful.

Comment: The exception would already be meaningful, and I can't imagine why a method such as this would be responsible for logging such an exception; it should almost certainly be something further up the stack.  I'm not saying it's literally never appropriate to avoid having the exception thrown, but to say that it's wrong to call the method that throws an exception, just because there are a few niche situations (that don't appear to apply here) in which it might be worth avoiding calling the method that throws isn't appropriate.

Comment: @Servy you see how meaningful it was for op. If you don't give it additional context("Could not load phones by carrier-id because the carrierId was not a valid integer:" + carrierid) it might be difficult to understand the original reason, all the more if it's handled somewhere else(if at all). It's best practices to log where something happens and not somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Sandy - based on your comment, you might try setting up your arguments like this instead:

```
public JsonResult LoadPhonesByCarrierId(string emailaddress, int carrierid = 0) {
```

Then just make sure you are handling the zero case so that you aren't trying to fetch when you wouldn't get anything back.

Answer (score 0):

My simple suggestion here is to use the appropriate types. If you are sure you are getting either an int value or no value, you should consider using the nullable int type as your parameter. With this approach, you do not need to call the TryParse method on your string parameter. All you need to check whether your nullable int parameter is null or not. If not null, you may use the `Value` property to get the int value.

```
public JsonResult LoadPhonesByCarrierId(string emailaddress,int? carrierId)
{
   if(carrierId!=null)
   {
      // to do : use carrierId.Value to do the filtering
   }
   //to do : Return something
}
```

Comment: I was trying to do that but I didn't  implemented correctly because it gave me more errors.